# Is the decimal component of the square root of 2 (i.e. sqrt(2) - 1) a named constant? Is it broadly significant?

Tags: geometry, constants

I was doing some geometry with circles locked on a grid, and I noticed that the distance between a unit circle and the corner of a square that it is inscribed in is of length $\sqrt{2} - 1$, or roughly $.41421356237$. Does this number have a widely-recognized name, and does it pop up in seemingly unrelated situations in the way that [pi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEfHFsfGXjs) or [the golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Applications_and_observations) do?

Granted, the primary purpose of such names are to create shorthand, and $\sqrt{2} - 1$ isn't very long to begin with. Still, it's not much less cumbersome than the mathematical expressions that define the first few [metallic ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_mean), which are nonetheless named. Furthermore, if we re-scale the geometry to involve a unit square instead of unit circle, then the similar line segment is of length $\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$, which is closely reminiscent of the metallic ratios. I can easily imagine that constant being named rather than the first one.

Comment: your number is the reciprocal of the [silver ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_ratio)

Comment: Ooh, thank you. I think that explains why nobody would bother to name it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some significance to this constant in the theory of **quasilattices**.  While the best-known cases involve fivefold symmetry, [eightfold examples have also been realized in quasicrystalline materials in the laboratory](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/104/66003).  So this eightfold quasilattice concept is a thing indeed.

We may then render the vertices of a regular octagon as quasilattice points, and then identify a quasiperiodic ratio by comparing the length of a side of the octagon with that of a parallel diagonal.  If we divide the diagonal by the side, we get a ratio of $\sqrt2+1$; with the reverse division it comes out to $\sqrt2-1$ (in the fivefold case we would use a pentagon instead, in which case the ratio between side and parallel diagonal would be $(\sqrt5\pm1)/2$).  Both period ratios are consistent with the same quasilattice structure because they differ by a whole number.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what some of this means, but I'll give it to you. Thanks!

Comment: See [this introduction](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.46.4567%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ved=2ahUKEwj29rOwgabvAhVSVs0KHSC-DZcQFjANegQIChAS&usg=AOvVaw3GfG4tIZagN28CYw26F7qo), noting especially the appearance of octagon in Fig. 2.1 and Pentagon's in Fig. 3.1.